# Stop link-forward when clicking on button with form-action

Tags: php, html, input, html-email

I have created this code that allows to calculate som values.
When clicking on the calculate-button it simply shows the result. By itself the code works perfectly fine.

To being able to log the data, it also sends an email of the inserted values by using a form and an action linked to a php-file. After adding this form to the code, it wrongfully redirects to the forms action-url. Ideally it it should show the result of the calculation on the webpage without reloading or redirecting when pressing the button.

I've tried to use "return false" without any luck. When changing/adding the button-type, it will either block the function of the calculation or redirect.

**HTML-file:**

```
<form action="/php/calcA.php" method="POST" role="form">
    <p>Value A</p>
    <input type="number" id="num1" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="num1" required="required" data-error="Value is required.">
    <p>Value B</p>
    <input type="number" id="num2" style="text-align: center; class="form-control" name="num2" required="required" data-error="Value is required."></p>

    <button type="button" onClick="calculate()" class="btn btn-primary blueline" style="color: #FFF; font-weight: 700;">Calculate</button>
    <br>
    <h4 class="main" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; background: #1CBC55; color: #FFF; text-align: left; font-weight: bold" id="answer">Savings in total:</h4>     
<script>
    function calculate(){
        var field1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var field2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

        var result=parseFloat(field1)*parseFloat(field2)-(2000*parseFloat(field1));

     if(!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Savings in total: €"+result+".00 excl. VAT";
     }

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "php/calcA.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</form>
```

**PHP-file:**

```
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];

    $email_from = 'Data from calcA';
    $email_subject = 'Data from CalcA';
    $email_body =
                "$num1\n".
                "$num2\n"

    $to = "data@youremail.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `button` with default type as `submit` so it will always redirect to the `action` page.
You can change your `button` to `type="button"` and send an `ajax` request from `calculate()` function to`/php/calcA.php` page to send mail.

Comment: I'm fairly new to ajax, but as you can see in the code, it now sends the email. Unfortunately, the email doesn't contain the values entered in "num1" and "num2". I've tested the php-file, which works perfectly fine, so I would like to think that it needs an element for the ajax query.

I've updated the code in the original post.

Comment: Replace `xhttp.send()` with `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("num1=field1&num2=field2");`

Comment: Hi Atal Prateek, great feedback. Step by step I start to understand multiple elements. While I can follow the idea of your comment, the result is that I get an email with the actual text "field1" and "field2", not the actual inserted value. Is it some formatting issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got it: ("num1="+field1+"&num2="+field2);

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tell Javascript to prevent the form posting:

```
<form action="/php/calcA.php" method="POST" role="form" onsubmit="return handleForm();">
    <blah></blah>
<form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // form will now not submit    
        // do your thing!
    }
</script>
```